# Starting httpd as service using a non-Administrator account

Tags: windows, apache, windows-services

I installed Apache in it's default directory under `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2`. During the installation process, a service `Apache2.2` was created.

When using the *Apache Monitor* application or the Windows *Services* tool as a user with administrator privileges, I am able to start and stop the service without problem and it serves websites and everything seems to work fine.

For security reasons, I would like to start the httpd server from a user account with limited privileges.

After digging through some documentation and using [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to debug any file and registry access problems, I think I got the permissions for the files and directories right - only a few failed accesses to C:\ and to the EventLog registry entry show up in ProcessMonitor when trying to start the service.

Nevertheless, it fails with the error message

> Windows could not start the Apache2.2 on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. (...)

This event log shows the following message:

> (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: Invalid config file path C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\httpd.conf

Since I read that httpd doesn't accept backslashes (although they seem to work when started by a user with administrator rights), I changed the services' parameters to use forward-slashes, quoted, unquoted, removed them, made them relative (in order to remove spaces from them) such as `../conf/httpd.conf` and other variants, but without success so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache webserver seems to traverse all directories starting from `C:\` down the hierarchy until it reaches the directory where it finds `httpd.conf`. For the question, these directories are:

```
C:\
C:\Program Files\
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\
```

To solve the problem, all these directories need to have the *List Folder Contents* privilege set for the user account under which `httpd` is executed.

The error messsage it gives in the event log is therefore misleading, the path is correct.

To avoid having to change the permission settings for all these folders, I would recommend installing Apache in a direct subdirectory of `C:\`, such as `C:\Apache2.2\`.